# Sequence of arrows circling around

Tags: graphics, tikz-arrows

I imagine that the code for this is quite simple, so I hope this isn't too rude/bold of a request:

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. The post suggests you might be looking for someone to write the code for you (hmm...), but the title suggests you might be looking for something else.

Comment: "looking for someone to write the code for you" congrats on reading through a wall with $\varepsilon$ thickness. As I suspected, the code is quite short. I really don't see an issue with a small request like this. Put yourself in my shoes -- what would you do? I already googled around for Tikz examples, but to no avail.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere.  It seems from your question that you are aware of the "do it for me" issue; so, even if you have no clue, try nonetheless to include something that you attempted, even if it does not work.  Some of my own "trys", when I look back at them later seem incredibly bad, but including _something_, other than a bare graphic, at least shows some self effort.  See _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3350/90087  Also, you might go ahead and accept the other answers you have received in prior posts if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the simple case shown in your screenshot, the facilities of the `amscd` package should suffice. To get the user guide of this package, open a command window, type `texdoc amsldoc`, and find the section on commutative diagrams.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amscd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{CD}
A  @>>> B  @>>> C \\
@.      @.      @VVV\\
F  @<<< E  @<<< E \\
\end{CD}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative at the best answer of @Mico, you could use also [tikz-cd](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) to create commutative diagrams.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r] & C \arrow[d] \\
F & E \arrow[l] & E \arrow[l]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```